# how should I handle an expired JWT

Tags: api, authentication, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I am new to JWTs and I have a question about it.
I have a web app with React, Node.js, express, using axios for ajax calls and npm jsonwebtokens for the access tokens.

I read a lot about JWT access tokens and refresh tokens but still one thing is not clear to me.
let's say a user logged in, got his access token and a refresh token, the access token will expire in 15 minutes.
What is the best way to go about it ?

1. set a timeout that will execute an API call to get a new access token after 15 minutes (let's say 14.5 minutes to be on the safe side)
2. set an interceptor that will check if the token is still valid and if not first get a new token and then continue with the request
3. is there another way I didn't considered?

If number 1 is the best way how do I handle a page refresh? the way I have it setup right now is when a user is logging in the login function calls a _refreshCountDown function that:

- counts the time until the token expiration - with a setTimeout function
- execute the refresh_token API call
- call it self back again to start a new countdown based on the new expiration time

now if a user refreshes the page the login function is not being called therefore the _refreshCountDown is never being called.
how would you have handle this scenario?

will appreciate any answer
thanks :)

Comment: I would opt with 2. The interceptor fires before you go to a server. It checks whether the token looks like it expired. If this is so, you first refresh the token.

Comment: thank you for the response. Wouldn't it effect performances as every call will take more time to execute if the token expired?

Comment: Assuming your token lifetime is 15 minutes, you don't delay **every** call, just the one that would end up with an error. This one has to be preceded with token refresh call.